# TYPO3 8 with extbase: remove FileReference

Tags: typo3, extbase

This seems simple enough but I seem to be too stupid to do it. I have added a field to fe_users called "cv" for uploading a pdf file. In my FrontendUser Model it looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
 * @cascade remove
 */
protected $cv;
```

Uploading a file works like a charm, I used the script from https://github.com/helhum/upload_example in parts.

The only problem is deleting such a file, or rather, removing the connection between sys_file and the user. After submitting a form and checking a checkbox, I tried to do this:

```
$user->setCv(null);
$user->setEdited(new \DateTime());
$this->frontendUserRepository->update($user);
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

After a page reload if I take a look at the backend, the cv File is still attached to the user (but "edited" was correctly set to the current datetime). I do not understand this, how can I set the FileReference Value to null?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your Model. `FileReferences` are stored in an M:N relation. So you must use the folling declaration in your Model:

```
/**
 * cv
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
 * @cascade remove
 */
protected $cv = null;
```

with an initialization in the `__constructor`:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->cv = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}
```

Now you have your `FileReference` in an `ObjectStorage`. To clear all `FileReferences` you can set `cv` to `new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage()`:

```
$user->removeCv(new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage()); 
$user->setEdited(new \DateTime()); 
$this->frontendUserRepository->update($user); 
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

Comment: If I store them in an m:n relation, is it still possible to create a form with the property? if so - how?

Comment: They are stored in an m:n relation, you have no change to use an 1:1 since this is defined in the `TCA` for the `sys_file_reference` table. If you want to add an file to an `ObjectStorage` you can use `ObjectStorage->attach($file)`. If you don't want an m:n relation you can use `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File` instead.

Comment: Why would he use an ObejctStorage if CV is just a single file per user?

Comment: He use `FileReference` to assign the files. `FileReference` has a table definition for m:n relations. So TYPO3 think there are can be more than one file and Extbase wants an array to assign the `FileReference`. As I wrote: If he only wants one Image, he can use `File` instead of `FileReference`.